# Connection to the internet: ping vs HTTP

Tags: networking, router, dns

I am able to ping the ip address (e.g. 64.233.163.104) from my command line. But, when I am using the same ip address in the browser, its not working.

Comment: Sorry, there's not enough information in your question to tell anything about what's going on. Specifically, you need to define "not working." There are lots of things that can go wrong here; I suggest looking up how to do network connection troubleshooting. Or, if you [edit] your question, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [big difference between a simple ping and the GET in browser](https://serverfault.com/questions/282696/difference-between-a-ping-and-a-get-request):

Ping only checks if the remote host is answering ICMP packets, which (usually) means it's up and running; but this doesn't give you any information about which services the host is actually offering.

An HTTP GET request checks that there is a web server running on the host, that it answers to a given IP/port/hostname combo, that you asked it for a valid URL and that the web site is able to answer your request.

Example: if IIS (or Apache) is stopped on the host, it will very well answer a Ping request, but a HTTP GET will fail.

Answer (score 0):

i think that sounds like a dns problem, google would like to redirect you to your local search site (google.com to google.hu for hungarians for instance)
if the network work (ping works, so it should be fine) try using google's dns service, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in the network connection/properties/general